# Publishing Page - hide page layouts

Tags: publishing-site, page-layout, publishing, publishing-page

We have requirement to leave only article layouts for publishing pages and hide others (Redirect, Blank Web Part Page, Table of Contents, Splash etc should be hidden). Any ideas how we could achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Site Actions->Site Settings. Under Look and Feel click on Page layouts and site templates. You can select which page layouts you would like available here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new publishing content type and associate it with a custom layout page similar to article layout. You can then create a new document library and associate only your custom content type to this library. This way whenever you choose to create a new page inside this library only the custom page layout which you created becomes the available option.