# SPO Page Layouts

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I'm rather new with SharePoint in my site collection I'm trying to create a new page with multiple WebPart Zones as I have done in the past. Once I navigate to Site Contents > Pages > New Document > and I see the following 3 page layouts.

[image]

I'm not sure what changed I used to see more options as I was able to create a"Blank Web Part Page" in the past

[image]

I also enabled the "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features" and "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure"

[image]

I feel like I'm missing something small here, is there anything that I could be missing that is causing the Page Layout to be different or am I in the wrong setting for creating a WebPart Page?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, it appears that I have been playing around where I shouldn't. Linking the answer below in case someone else runs across this issue

Site Actions->Site Settings > Look and Feel > Page layouts and site templates. I then made sure I had the middle option "Any Layout" selected which resolved my issue as I had limited the scope.

[image]

[Publishing Page - hide page layouts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44269/publishing-page-hide-page-layouts?rq=1)

Comment: Plz accept your own answer as answer, so the question will not appear in Unanswered Questions List. Thanks you.